# RxJS missing values when using combineAll with 2 observables

Tags: typescript, rxjs, observable, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I'm trying to generate overs for a cricket match simulation with values as follows:

Overs -> 0 - 19 (total 20 overs)
Balls -> 1 - 6 (total 120, each over has 6 balls)

Hence the sequence that has to be generated would be something like `0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, ....., 19.4, 19.5, 19.6`

I can easily achieve this by iterating, using 2 nested loops, but since I am using angular with RxJS, I wanted to do this the reactive way. I came up with the following code which should work AFAIK:

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, combineAll } from 'rxjs/operators';

let overs = range(0, 20);

let balls = range(1, 6);

let ob = overs.pipe(
  map((over) => balls.pipe(
    map((ball) => `${over}.${ball}`)
  ))
).pipe(combineAll())

ob.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

But the problem with this is, it is missing a lot of values. I get the following output:

```
[ '0.6',
  '1.6',
  '2.6',
  '3.6',
  '4.6',
  '5.6',
  '6.6',
  '7.6',
  '8.6',
  '9.6',
  '10.6',
  '11.6',
  '12.6',
  '13.6',
  '14.6',
  '15.6',
  '16.6',
  '17.6',
  '18.6',
  '19.1' ]
[ '0.6',
  '1.6',
  '2.6',
  '3.6',
  '4.6',
  '5.6',
  '6.6',
  '7.6',
  '8.6',
  '9.6',
  '10.6',
  '11.6',
  '12.6',
  '13.6',
  '14.6',
  '15.6',
  '16.6',
  '17.6',
  '18.6',
  '19.2' ]
[ '0.6',
  '1.6',
  '2.6',
  '3.6',
  '4.6',
  '5.6',
  '6.6',
  '7.6',
  '8.6',
  '9.6',
  '10.6',
  '11.6',
  '12.6',
  '13.6',
  '14.6',
  '15.6',
  '16.6',
  '17.6',
  '18.6',
  '19.3' ]
[ '0.6',
  '1.6',
  '2.6',
  '3.6',
  '4.6',
  '5.6',
  '6.6',
  '7.6',
  '8.6',
  '9.6',
  '10.6',
  '11.6',
  '12.6',
  '13.6',
  '14.6',
  '15.6',
  '16.6',
  '17.6',
  '18.6',
  '19.4' ]
[ '0.6',
  '1.6',
  '2.6',
  '3.6',
  '4.6',
  '5.6',
  '6.6',
  '7.6',
  '8.6',
  '9.6',
  '10.6',
  '11.6',
  '12.6',
  '13.6',
  '14.6',
  '15.6',
  '16.6',
  '17.6',
  '18.6',
  '19.5' ]
[ '0.6',
  '1.6',
  '2.6',
  '3.6',
  '4.6',
  '5.6',
  '6.6',
  '7.6',
  '8.6',
  '9.6',
  '10.6',
  '11.6',
  '12.6',
  '13.6',
  '14.6',
  '15.6',
  '16.6',
  '17.6',
  '18.6',
  '19.6' ]
```

As one can observe, all overs are generated (0-19) but we are getting only the `.6` values with each. Only the last over, i.e. `19th` is having unique values `19.1, 19.2...`

What am I missing in this code?

Also, if it helps here's the repl for the above code in case you want to try and experiment with it in browser: https://repl.it/@ishankhare07/cricket-overs

Comment: As mentioned I know how to generate such a series using plain old javascript. What I'm trying to avoid is nested loops. As a matter of fact, I even managed to do in more ES6 style -- see this -> https://repl.it/@ishankhare07/cricket-overs-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need to use `combineAll` and use `mergeMap` instead which makes it more understandable.

```
import { range } from 'rxjs';
import { map, mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

let overs = range(0, 20);
let balls = range(1, 6);

let ob = overs.pipe(
  mergeMap((over) => balls.pipe(
    map((ball) => `${over}.${ball}`),
  )),
); 

ob.subscribe((val) => console.log(val));
```

Live demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-aud3ot

Comment: Excellent solution!